# Am4Chart unable to get instance to already chart

Tags: angular, amcharts, html2canvas, amcharts4

I am looking for a script to get an instance of the chart. I am only getting the following one.

```
var chart = am4core.getChart("chart", am4charts.XYChart);
chart.exporting.export("png");
```

The only issue I am having is it's creating a new instance of the chart resulting in destroying the current chart.

I want to use this chart instance and somehow export it to an image and then convert it into a PDF file along with some other data. I am using angular 5.2, html2canvas to download as PDF

Comment: Is there a reason to use html2canvas instead of amCharts built-in export to PDF feature? https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/exporting/#Using_export_API

Comment: Yes, I just don't need the graph PDF, I also need the print of the table that exists on the page. So my result PDF will contain, the graph image + the table Image.

Comment: amCharts use [pdfmake](http://pdfmake.org). You can use its instance to build custom PDF files as [shown in this tutorial](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/tutorials/generating-multi-content-pdf-export/).